# Excel: automatically split a table into multiple tables

Tags: excel, split, multiple-tables

I have a master table with multiple columns and rows, I want to split it automatically into multiple tables on different sheets according to a specific value.
EX: if I have the below table and I want it to be automatically split to 3 tables according to **item** type

Master Table

[image: Master Table]

the new tables should be like this:
Table:

[image: Table]

Chair

[image: Chair]

Comment: And what problem have you run into when you tried to do this?  (It is not clear to me from what you have written). Please provide the steps you have taken, or VBA code and the precise problems that you are not able to overcome.  It may help to read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Actually I am asking on how to it. I thought about using excel formulas but I didn't find any that can do it.

Comment: You can use the various lookup and/or index/match functions; you can use vba macros to filter and copy; there are many ways to rearrange your data. Please read the help articles I referenced above, and be aware that this is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.